# bazel build target that collects multiple libraries

Tags: bazel

I am not able to archive multiple libraries into a single library, for example :

```
cc_library(
name = "lib1",
srcs = ["src1.c"]
)

cc_library(
name = "lib2",
srcs = ["src2.c"]
)

cc_library(
name = "release-lib",
srcs = [":lib1",":lib2"]
```

when I run bazel build //release-lib
it will through INFO: Found 1 target...
target //release-lib up-to-date

but the target is never built in bazel-out

of course lib1,lib2 are added to linking command if I ever use release-lib as a dep for a cc_binary rule, however my final target is to have a whole archive of multiple libraries
is there a way to forcibly make bazel create and build this target !?

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, `cc_library` is only useful for including into a top-level target that performs the fully transitive link such as `cc_binary`. Building a transitive static library is not currently within the repertoire of the builtin Bazel C++ rules. However, there is a an extension rule to do it available here: https://gist.github.com/oquenchil/3f88a39876af2061f8aad6cdc9d7c045 One can also follow along https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1920 for the full sordid history.